# How to recover/re-mount a lost drive letter in Win10 WSL1?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Win10.21H2 and bothered by a long existing issue.

Demonstrate it below:

- Assuming I have drive E: on my Win10 host machine, so `ls /mnt/e` works OK in my WSL1 shell.
- Now, Let CMD launch `chkdsk /f E:` and wait for its completion.
- Go back to WSL1 shell, I find that `ls /mnt/e` fails with "Invalid argument".

[image: WSL1 fails to remount drive letter]

This happens as well if E: is a partition on an external USB harddisk, and you unplug and replug the harddisk, which is a more common scenario.

Then how to recover from this problem? My best effort now is to terminate the whole WSL session(`wsl -t Ubuntu-22.04` etc) and then re-run it. This overkills because it will force every Linux programs inside that WSL to terminal, quite inconvenient.

Any better way to recover my `/mnt/e' ?

Comment: Find "WslService" from task manager of services list and a "Restart" works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (in WSL1) after a forced dismount on a removable drive by `chkdsk /f`:

```
sudo umount /mnt/e
sudo mount -t drvfs E: /mnt/e
```

It should also work if the drive is unplugged/reattached.

I'm running Windows 11, but this WSL1 functionality hasn't changed in quite a while, so it should behave the same in Windows 10.