# WSL: Mounted drives are all the sudden not mounted anymore

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL I have the problem that rarely, unexpectedly, all mounted drives are not mounted anymore. What could be the reason for this? And is there a solution for this not to happen again (I don't want to reboot WSL)?

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1728549/how-to-recover-re-mount-a-lost-drive-letter-in-win10-wsl1) help ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the next time I get the unmounting problem.